# How do I make the values I am iterating into a list stop from duplicating the entire list plus one value over and over?

Tags: list, python-2.7, plot, iteration, anaconda

The title maybe a bit confusing or if I am not supposed to post here sorry but, I am having trouble with numerical values I am putting into a list continuously with the main objective that I want to plot the values in real time.

My problem is that once the code does the calculations it puts the value in a list and prints the whole list plus the new value. An example would [1] , [1,2],[1,2,3]

How can I prevent this from happening so I can use these values to graph in real time? I believe this is causing me to get the error [KeyError: 'text']

Here is my code:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json

import numpy

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""



#creates empty list
my_list = [] 
my_average = []
my_range = []
newlist = []

# This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        json_load = json.loads(data)
        texts = json_load['text']
        #print texts
        ***[CALCULATIONS]***
        my_list.append(r)
        #drop zero in list
        if 0 in my_list: my_list.remove(0)



        #calculate average
        average = numpy.mean(my_list)
        x = average[~numpy.isnan(average)]

        for i in x:
            if i not in newlist:
                newlist.append(i)

        print newlist       






auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())

# Searches by the keywords
stream.filter(track=['soil','gardening'],stall_warnings=True)
```

Thank you in advance and hope it makes sense.

P.S any suggestions for plotting the data in real time would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your code, but I suspect the issue you're having is due to using global lists. When you append to `my_list` or `newlist`, the values you're adding will remain there forever since the lists are never reinitialized.

Probably you want to be make one or both of those lists local variables in the `on_data` method. Just move their initialization code (e.g. `newlist = []`) into the function somewhere.

Comment: That seems to have worked regarding the numerical values not iterating but could you help me solve the problem of why some the output has no value in the brackets like so?

[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[0.5]
[0.5]
[]
[-0.20000000000000001]
[0.40000000000000002]
[]
[0.29999999999999999]
[0.34999999999999998]
[0.23333333333333331]
[-0.5]
[]
[]